How to find a class tag using htmltools::tagQuery with multiple classes?
I'm trying to tagQuery the div tag with the class sw-input-icon but I don't get any results. I do believe it is because there are multiple classes. How can I select the div.sw-input-icon tag?
library(htmltools)
library(shinyWidgets)

# <div class="form-group shiny-input-container">
#   <label class="control-label shiny-label-null" for="test" id="test-label"></label>
#     <div class="input-group">
#       <div class="input-group-addon sw-input-icon input-group-prepend">
#         <span class="input-group-text">Select:</span>
#           </div>
#           <input id="test" type="number" class="form-control numeric-input-icon" value="5"/>
#             </div>
#             <span class="help-block invalid-feedback hidden d-none"></span>
#               </div>

objct <-  numericInputIcon("test", NULL, 5, icon = "Select:")

tagQuery(objct)$
  find("div.input-group")

# Does not return anything
tagQuery(objct)$
find("div.input-group-addon sw-input-icon input-group-prepend")

# Does not return anything
tagQuery(objct)$
  find("div.sw-input-icon")

EDIT:
I found a bit of a tedious workaround using html2r. I converted the HTML code into shiny::tags:
objct <- 
  withTags(
div(class = "form-group shiny-input-container",
    label(class = "control-label shiny-label-null",
          `for` = "test",
          id = "test-label"),
    div(class = "input-group",
        div(class = "input-group-addon sw-input-icon input-group-prepend",
            span(class = "input-group-text",
                 "Select:")),
        input(id = "test",
              type = "number",
              class = "form-control numeric-input-icon",
              value = "5")),
    span(class = "help-block invalid-feedback hidden d-none"))

)

After that, I can query the objct properly and add a style
tagQuery(objct)$
  find("div.sw-input-icon")$
  addAttrs(style = "width: 75px")$
  allTags()


If you look into objct, you'll see that it's not a tag list in the sense that tagQuery can look at it all. Specifically look at objct$children[[2]]$children[[1]] everything within div.input-group is written as a tag function, not the literal tags themselves. I'm sure there's another way to achieve your objective, what are you trying to do with the tag when you capture it? Modify it?

@Kat I'm trying to capture the tag and add a style. I'm a bit surprised that you cant look at it all, especially when the first find("div.input-group") worked. But, words as tag function and literal tags are new words for me. I managed to find a work around (see my edit) but it seems a bit tedious. If you have another solution, I would love to see it.

Are you using this within a Shiny app? If so, you can using tag$style, which should be a bit easier. With or without Shiny you could use htmlwidgets::onRender to add the style after rendering.  In both of these others, you could still use numericInputIcon initially.

tagQuery works very neatly if all the elements were indeed created with its corresponding tag constructors, but - as you have noticed - fail as soon as one of the children is either a literal HTML string or - as in your case - a tag function.
What you need to do is to make sure the shiny.tag.function is replaced by the tags it represents, you can do it like this:
objct_rendered <- rapply(objct, as.tags, 
                         classes = "shiny.tag.function", how = "replace")

This tells R to replace all shiny.tag.functions by its tags recursively. Now that the children are tags your tagQuery will work like a charm:
tagQuery(objct_rendered)$
  find("div.sw-input-icon")$
  addAttrs(style = "width: 75px")$
  allTags()

# <div class="form-group shiny-input-container">
#   <label class="control-label shiny-label-null" for="test" id="test-label"></label>
#   <div class="input-group">
#     <div class="input-group-addon sw-input-icon input-group-prepend" style="width: 75px">
#       <span class="input-group-text">Select:</span>
#     </div>
#     <input id="test" type="number" class="form-control numeric-input-icon" value="5"/>
#   </div>
#   <span class="help-block invalid-feedback hidden d-none"></span>
# </div>


Just for the record, sometimes you also have literal HTML code inside a tag, which prevents tagQuery from finding elements either:
obj <- div(class = "outer", HTML("<div class=\"inner\"></div>"))

tagQuery(obj)$find(".inner")$length()
# [1] 0

The only (reliabe) workaround I found in this case (regex would be potential another solution, but it feels even more hackish) is as follows:

Parse the HTML using xml2::read_html
Use XPath to find the element of interest
Modify it
Return the character representation of the modified object

Admittedly, that is quiet a detour, but at least you can modify even these beasts:
library(xml2)

get_xpath_class <- function(cls) {
  paste0('//div[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), ',
            '" ', cls, ' ")]')
}

htm <- as.character(obj) %>%
  read_html()
htm %>%
  xml_find_first(get_xpath_class("inner")) %>%
  xml_set_attr("style", "color: red")

htm %>% 
  xml_find_first("/html/body/div") %>%
  as.character() %>%
  cat()

# <div class="outer"><div class="inner" style="color: red"></div></div>

